# 2 Time picker in Same activity

Tags: android, timepicker

Can anyone help me to implement two time picker in same activity and store its 4 value (hour,minute) into 4 different variables....
My code is as below (not working)...

public class Time extends AppCompatActivity{

```
static final int START_TIME_ID=0;
static final int END_TIME_ID=1;

EditText edit_start_time,edit_end_time;

public int hour,minute;
private int chour,cminute;

public Time(){
    final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    chour=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    cminute=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Time);
    edit_start_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_start_time);
    edit_end_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_end_time);

edit_start_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(START_TIME_ID);
        }
    });

    edit_end_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            showDialog(END_TIME_ID);
        }
    });
```

}

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mStartTime=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofday,int min)
    {
        hour=hourofday;
        minute=min;
    }
};

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mEndTime=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofday,int min)
    {
        hour=hourofday;
        minute=min;
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case START_TIME_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mStartTime,chour,cminute,false);
        case END_TIME_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mEndTime,chour,cminute,false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Understand this code,

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener showTimePicker = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.startTime)
              //todo stuff
          else if(view.getId() == R.id.endTime)
              //todo stuff
        }
    };
startTime.setOnClickListener(showTimePicker);
endTime.setOnClickListener(showTimePicker);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view

No need to make two time picker. take one boolean variable. when click on edit_start_time then value equal to true and when click on edit_end_time change it into false.

On the basis of boolean variable set your 4 different variables value.

hope it help you.

Comment: I implemented it. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help

```
public class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
TextView textView;
Context context;
private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

public TimePicker(EditText text, Context context) {
    this.text= textView;
    this.context = context;
}

public TimePicker() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Time t = new Time(hourOfDay,minute,0);//seconds by default set to zero
    Format formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String time = formatter.format(t);
      textView.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
}
```

}

**usage**

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(editTextName, getActivity());
timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Start Time");
```